# Use ActivityContext in service for Custom Listner

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, service, android-context

PrimaryDashBoard where i use LocatinListener and retrieve the location from the service

```
public class PrimaryDashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
public LatLng myLatLng=new LatLng(0.0,0.0);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_primary_dashboard);

        try {
           Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationManager.class);

            startService(i);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLatLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

}

@Override
public void GPSDisabled(String errorMessage) {

}

@Override
public void GPSEnabled() {
}
 }
```

Here is LocationListner

```
    public interface LocationListener {
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location);

public  void GPSDisabled(String errorMessage);

public void GPSEnabled();
  }
```

Here is my Service where i want to initilized the LocationListner and want to update the location values from the listners

```
   public class LocationManager extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = LocationManager.class.getSimpleName();
// Registered callbacks
public LocationListener locationUpdate;
public static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.locationUpdate = (LocationListener)  getApplicationContext();

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext());

    createLocationCallback();
    createLocationRequest();
    buildLocationSettingsRequest();

    if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

}

@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
}

public LocationManager() {
    super("locationManager");

}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

/**
 * Creates a callback for receiving location events.
 */
private void createLocationCallback() {
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            PrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setLastLatLng(Double.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude()), Double.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude()));
            if (locationUpdate != null)
                locationUpdate.onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }
    };
}


private void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
}


private void startLocationUpdates() {

    // Begin by checking if the device has the necessary location settings.
    mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {

                    LogCat.show("All location settings are satisfied.");
                    if (locationUpdate != null)
                        locationUpdate.GPSEnabled();
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    switch (statusCode) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            if (locationUpdate != null)
                                locationUpdate.GPSDisabled("Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade location settings ");
                            LogCat.show("Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade location settings ");
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                // result in onActivityResult().
                                ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                rae.startResolutionForResult((Activity) getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                    "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                            LogCat.show(errorMessage);
                            if (locationUpdate != null)
                                locationUpdate.GPSDisabled(errorMessage);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                    }


                }
            });
}



}
```

This line of code create me a problem because it want Activity context, when it will not be a service and i pass activity Context it works perfect.

> this.locationUpdate = (LocationListener)  getApplicationContext();
>
> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to driver.com.driver.LocationComponents.LocationListener
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service driver.com.driver.LocationComponents.LocationManager: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to driver.com.driver.LocationComponents.LocationListener
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , Your application class does not implement the `LocationListener` interface so your are getting this error.  You cannot get  the Activity instance inside your intent service , because 1) It may no longer be active 2) Intent Service can be started from other services or broadcast receivers. In order to communicate the `LocationListener` methods with your activity , you need to use a [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager).

Comment: yes but i want Location if the application is closed

Comment: if i pass Static reference of PrimaryDashboard it works